# slow down execution of javascript's eval

Tags: javascript, timer, eval, karel

I have created a little robot like the Karel robot ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karel_%28programming_language%29)) which is based on javascript.

[Karel4Web](http://abi-physik.de/_niki/niki.php)

The robot can be controlled with some simple commands such as "forward", "turnright" and so on.

The user can write a javascript program to control the robot which then goes through javascripts "eval()" function so that the robot moves.

**The problem is that I want the robot to move slowly so that you can see what he is doing and so that you can highlight the current code line in the editor.**

**Current method: Parsing**

At the moment I have solved this (in the offline version) by parsing each line in the textarea and then building a stack of action which are then executed one after another with window.setTimeout. But this is of course limited because I have to write parsing code for every little javascript language contruct which is much work and error prone.

Some additional information to this:

Parsing version: http://abi-physik.de/_niki2/niki.php

Parsing version js code: http://abi-physik.de/_niki2/js/niki.js

Important functions are at the bottom of the script: run(), execute()

I am currently parsing the user script line by line and adding the actions to a stack. If the parser encounters an "if" it will begin a new stack and add all actions to that stack. if the parser then encounters an "}" it will close the "if" stack and continue to add actions to the base stack.

Any idea to improve this?

Comment: Have you tried splitting lines on ";" or \n then passing to eval one by one

Comment: I thought about it, but I did not try it yet. What will happen to if-conditions?

Comment: In this case also you will have to implement things for if , while loop. 
You can combine them into single code block but it will not show animation.

Comment: Edited your post to fix the URLs for you, as they're clearly relevant, so deserve to be proper links

Comment: Are you planning on having nested whiles and for loops?  `while( while() )`

Comment: @epascarello Yes I plan on having nested loops and if-conditions and I have updated the parsing algorithm so that it seems to work (no for loop yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say have those functions register to some queue instead of having them execute the JavaScript directly.

```
var moveQueue = [];

function forward(){
  moveQueue.push(_forward);
}
function _forward(){
    alert("move forward");
}

function backward(){
  moveQueue.push(_backward);
}
function _backward(){
    alert("move backward");
}
```

Than when it runs you would use a setTimeout and

```
function run(){
    var curStep = 0;
   function go(){
      moveQueue[curStep]();
      curStep++;
      if(curStep<moveQueue.length){
          window.setTimeout(go,500);
      }
   }  
}
```

You still would need to parse it out to figure out the if statement logic, but this is one of many ways that will allow you to control the speed of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a `sleep()` function, so yes, using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is the way to go.

You could parse the 'instructions' first, assemble an array of actions that need to be carried out, then use `setInterval` to arrange for a function to be regularly called which takes the next instruction and carries it out (or clears the interval, if there are no more instructions waiting to be processed).

Comment: That's roughly what I am doing (see js code, I have updated the question). The problem is that I have to implement things as while-loop, for-loop, functions and so on which is much work and error prone.